# Maximum number of hops between two points

Tags: r

I have this dataset:

```
From  To
-  -
1  5
1  7
1  8
1  17
2  11
3  5
3  17
4  7
5  12
5  13
5  17
8  13
8  17
13 17
```

What is the best way to store the above data in R?  Also how to find the longest path between two points in R? In the above example longest path between 3 and 17 is `3 - 5 - 13 - 17`. The possible paths from 3 to 17 are:

```
3 - 17
3 - 5 - 17
3 - 5 - 13 - 17
```

The path with the maximum number of hops is `3 - 5 - 13 - 17`.

Comment: Hi @Jhudge welcome to SO! In order for us to help you with your problem you'll need to create a reproducible example, so that we can import it and play with it. Also, please frame your problem so that we understand the context. From what you've written, we have no idea of what you want or what you mean by the longest path.

Comment: you could read in as a `data.frame` (see `read.table`), convert this to a graph using the  `igraph` package( `graph_from_data_frame`) then find the `all_simple_paths` (and see which has the greatest number of nodes)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @user20650, `igraph` is a good way to go

Your data

```
df <- read.table(text="From  To
1  5
1  7
1  8
1  17
2  11
3  5
3  17
4  7
5  12
5  13
5  17
8  13
8  17
13 17", header=TRUE)
```

Convert data frame to graph

```
library(igraph)
G <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
```

Max # of hops

```
start <- 3
max(lengths(all_simple_paths(G, start)))
# 4
```

Comment: Thanks. This is great. Is there a way to detect/discount cycles?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for. If you look at the output of `all_simple_paths(G, start)`, you might see what you're asking for.